# Load image by extension in folder using C#

Tags: c#, openfiledialog

I have OpenFileDialog name of1.
How to load all image with extension (.png) in a folder by C#?

Comment: What do you want to do? Read all PNG files in a directory? Set *.png as filter for OpenFileDialog? Get list of selected files in OpenFileDialog? Did you try anything/search on MSDN for what you need?

Answer (score -1):

you want to load all images in of1 or what ?

If you want just to load images in an array, do this:

```
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(@"yourFolderPath");

FileInfo[] myImages = di.GetFiles("*.PNG");
```

Please, describe in more detail.